# Improve performance of Mysql query (lots of rows, and timestamp "problem")

Tags: mysql, performance

First of all, I want to say that the design of the database has been given to me, and I have been asked to improve the performance of the queries.  I am not supposed to modify the fields of the table (I believe moving some chars to int would improve performance...).

The table has **lots of rows** (I've around 14*10^6 rows, and growing...)

I would like to improve performance for queries like this one:

```
SELECT 
    timestampms/1000 as secs, 
    round(avg(data),2) as data, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampms/1000,'%m/%Y') as control 
FROM externalsensor 
WHERE (model='electric' and id=4 AND sensorid='TRI1VA' AND rawdata < 65535 ) 
    AND timestampms BETWEEN '1272454583000' AND '1303990583000' 
GROUP BY control 
ORDER BY secs ASC;
```

The mentioned table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `externalsensor` (
  `model` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'desconocido',
  `timestampms` char(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amtype` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `interval` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `counter` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sensorid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rawdata` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` decimal(20,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `temps` (`timestampms`),
  KEY `sensor` (`model`,`id`,`sensorid`,`timestampms`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The explained select shows:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table          | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | externalsensor | range | temps,sensor  | sensor | 92      | NULL | 194443 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The query took **20 seconds**, and I would like to know if anyone sees a way to improve the query. Appreciate any suggestions :)

**UPDATE**

After all the awesome recommendations, and such a lesson of MySql these guys have given to me, I've decided to do the following:

Since what I want is a *summary* of data by months (in a year), weeks (in a year), and hours (in a day), I've decided to create a **summary table** that has all that information, and is updated automatically by a script in the cron.

By doing that I am not querying **200.000 rows**, and I believe it's going to improve.  Of course, I'm going to take into account all the recommendations about indices, char->int and everything these guys have suggested.

I have not started to develop that, but as soon as I finish and I have new results, I will update this post with them.

I wish I could accept all the answers, but that is not possible... Thank you all.

Comment: how many matching rows are there?

Comment: Is there any way you can ditch the group?

Comment: I take the EXPLAIN to say that you return 194443 rows?

Comment: @Alnitak: 198844 rows...
@Nanne: Which group do you mean?  I'm thinking on creating summary tables by dates...So I can ditch a particular interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to remove computation from the select by storing them in the table.

In your case `timestampms/1000 as secs` and `FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampms/1000,'%m/%Y') as control` could be precomputed in a **secs** field and a **control** field, filled with ON INSERT and ON UPDATE **triggers**. You do not modify fields, you add some.

'control' is used on the GROUP BY, so you should get a nice benefit by adding index on this new control column. 'secs' is used for sorting, so the same apply. You'll may even need some indexes based on both columns.

Comment: that's a good point. I will try that, and post results.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change the type of `timestampms` to `bigint(15) unsigned` - you currently have 5 expressions that would require MySQL to cast that field from a string to integer prior to calculating it. And as Pentium10 has suggested - do `ORDER BY timestampms`.

Also, you don't need to specify `rawdata < 65535` in your `WHERE` statement as 65535 is the maximum value of an unsigned smallint anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Actually the condition is wrong: I don't want any 65535 values to be returned, so I should have written rawdata <> 65535.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here:

- You are doing an order by on a calculated field, which means that you are sorting the result set instead of selecting from an index.
- You are doing a function call for every row in the table, this slows things down and uses alot of CPU.

To fix it:

- Pre calculate all fields, using a batch update or triggers
- changerawdata test to not equal to 65535
- create an index with all fields in the where clause.

Comment: I see your point, and thanks for your answer.  The only think I'm wondering is, where should I put the rawdata condition? I don't want any rows with 65535 rawdata to be returned.

Comment: My bad, but instead of less than do a not equal to 65535

Comment: Not your bad, my bad I didn't do "the not equal" :)

Answer (score 1):

Order by a real field (timestampms), not a calculated field.

Try using "GROUP BY "timestampms/1000" rather than "control".

At the mysql ui, query on these individually:

WHERE model='electric'

WHERE id=4

WHERE sensorid='TRI1VA'

WHERE rawdata < 65535

WHERE timestampms BETWEEN '1272454583000' AND '1303990583000'

Then whichever has the fewest rows returned, make sure you have an index on the field in the first position.

That's a rough approach, you can add fields to the index from there.

The calculated expressions in the SELECT list won't make any difference. "rawdata" in the where clause is fine if you need it.

Do you really need it to return 194,000 rows? Fetching that many will take quite a while in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like on that data volume you need to **partition** your tables based on some condition, like time.

You could still look into to improve by indexes.

```
SELECT timestampms / 1000                         AS secs, 
       Round(Avg(data), 2)                        AS data, 
       From_unixtime(timestampms / 1000, '%m/%Y') AS control 
FROM   externalsensor 
WHERE  ( model = 'electric' 
         AND id = 4 
         AND sensorid = 'TRI1VA' 
         AND rawdata < 65535 ) 
       AND timestampms BETWEEN '1272454583000' AND '1303990583000' 
GROUP  BY control 
ORDER  BY timestampms ASC;
```

Create a sample table with lot smaller data set, then try this compound index

```
index(model,id,sensorid,rawdata,timestampms,control,data)
```

post back the explain output.

Comment: @Pentium10: It is possible to create an index with fields that are not declared as columns in the "CREATE TABLE"?.  It makes sense for the mentioned select, but control,secs,DATA are not fields from externalsensor table.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that. That is something that both of us missed. Order by needs to be changed. And no, cannot create index on those.

Comment: @Pentium10:  So Order BY timestampms instead of secs, and do you recommend creating a new index?

Comment: I was talking for 7 hours of that. Didn't you try?

Comment: @Pentium10: I did not have my data set.  I've tried changing the ORDER BY, and it has improved.  My doubt is refering to the index in your answer, because that can't be done when there are no control and data fields. So I was wondering if you were suggesting another kind of index.

Comment: I see you have all columns for the index. Can you please review, and point out the column that is missing

Comment: @Pentium10: I don't have a column called control.

Comment: Take that out from the index list.